# How can I find out why a task is running?

Tags: ansible

I'm working with a complicated Ansible system with a lot of roles in various repositories. When I run a certain playbook, a task is running that I think shouldn't be. Is there a way to find out what triggered it?

Comment: This is a good question. There are multiple ways to specify task and role dependencies in ansible, i.e. `import_` and `include_` directives, role `dependencies` and more. Ansible does not provide a simple way to trace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible does not provide at the moment any tools to visualize the task and roles dependency tree.

What you could do though is

1. Get a list of tasks with the `--list-tasks` option from `ansible-playbook`.
2. Consider the list of tasks from the top level playbook in the order of appearance and mark these top-level tasks in the list.
3. Determine where the task that you are interested in appears between the marked tasks.
4. Make a playbook that includes only the marked task that appears directly below the task that you are interested.
5. Repeat `1` through `5` until the path through role and task dependencies is recovered.

### Example

This description is too general so here is an example taken from a real site.

```
ansible-playbook --list-tasks site.yml
```

outputs some 900 lines. The playbook contains multiple plays and we are interested in a play that applies to a specific group of hosts called `computeservers`.

The play may look like this:

```
- hosts:
    - computeservers
  roles: 
    - basic-pkg
    - ntp
    - zabbix
    - slurm
    - jupyter
    - gitlab-ci
```

Suppose we would like to know why the task `Install compilers` is running on this group of nodes.

Suppose we know (using `grep`) that this task belongs to the role called `compilers`. We see that `compilers` is not in the list of top-level roles, so it is somewhere down the dependency tree.

In the task list we look for a play that starts with

```
  play #2 (computeservers): nodes   TAGS: []
    tasks:
       basic-pkg : task1
       basic-pkg : task2
       ...
       slurm : task1
       slurm : task2
       ...
       compilers : Install compilers
       ...
       jupyter : task1
       ...
```

So we see that our task of interest `Install compilers` is somewhere between top-level roles `slurm` and `jupyter`. Therefore we need to further investigate the `jupyter` role.

This `jupyter` role may have a dependency

```
dependencies:
  - scipy
```

Eventually you would recover the path in the role dependency tree that leads to the task in question. In our example that would be

```
jupyter -> scipy -> anaconda -> compilers -> Install compilers
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansible runs all tasks in the order they are listed by default. A task executing that you did not expect implies some conditional. Typically when: expressions,  handlers, or includes.

You need to debug this like you would software. Find the simplest test case. Print out the state, such as using the debug module.  For more specific advice, post your (sanitized of sensitive information) playbook and roles.